# ¿Cómo devolver una entidad por medio de una consulta linq?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

Trabajo en una consulta `linq` en la cual deseo devolver una entidad, el código es el siguiente.

```
public ProductoExtend BuscarXCodigo(string valor)
    {
        using (var context = new BusinessContext())
        {
            var result = (from p in context.Productos
                                     join pp in context.ProductoPrecios
                                     on p.ProductoId equals pp.ProductoId
                                     where p.Codigo == valor & pp.Cantidad == 1
                                     select new ProductoExtend()
                                     {
                                         ProductoId = p.ProductoId,
                                         ProductoNombre = p.Nombre,
                                         Pvp = pp.Pvp
                                     });
            return (ProductoExtend)result;
        }
    }
```

El error que me da es el siguiente:

> No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[TecSoftware.EntidadesDominio.ProductoExtend]'
>   al tipo 'TecSoftware.EntidadesDominio.ProductoExtend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta con este código:

```
public ProductoExtend BuscarXCodigo(string valor)
{
    using (var context = new BusinessContext())
    {
        var result = (from p in context.Productos
                                 join pp in context.ProductoPrecios
                                 on p.ProductoId equals pp.ProductoId
                                 where p.Codigo == valor & pp.Cantidad == 1
                                 select new ProductoExtend()
                                 {
                                     ProductoId = p.ProductoId,
                                     ProductoNombre = p.Nombre,
                                     Pvp = pp.Pvp
                                 }).FirstOrDefault<ProductoExtend>();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Más info:

[Consultas Linq a Entidad](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/querying-entity-graph-in-entity-framework.aspx)

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, he solucionado mi requerimiento.